# What is meant by "inherit" in css?

Tags: html, css

How does `inherit` work here?

Specifically, I need to understand this [`inherit` code example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_inherit), from w3schools:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
span {
    color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.extra span {
    color: inherit;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
Here is <span>a span element</span> which is blue, as span elements are set to be.
</div>

<div class="extra" style="color:green">
Here is <span>a span element</span> which is green, because it inherits from     its parent.
</div>

<div style="color:red">
Here is <span>a span element</span> which is blue, as span elements are set     to be.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How does `inherit` work in this tag? I need clear answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break down the example code.

```
<style>
span {
    color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.extra span {
    color: inherit;
}
</style>
```

So, the first `span` block is saying "color all span elements blue by default, and give them a 1px solid black border".

The `.extra span` block is a more specific rule than the `span` block, and the most-specific block describing a particular element will take precedence over less-specific blocks. However, any `span` tag in this HTML page will first apply the most general block (`span {}`), and then apply the other matching blocks in order of specificity on top of each previous block in the chain. So, `<span>` tags contained inside an element of class `extra`, will first have `color: blue` and `border: 1px solid black` applied to them. After the first `span {}` block is applied, the `.extra span {}` block will be applied. Since `.extra span` says nothing about borders, the border from the `span {}` block will be used. This is a large part of where the "Cascading" part of "Cascading Style Sheets" comes from.

Now, with the basics out of the way, what does `inherit` do? As [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp) says:

> The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value from its parent *element*.

Let's look at the HTML again:

```
<div class="extra" style="color:green">
    Here is <span>a span element</span> which is green, because it inherits from its parent.
</div>
```

In this case, the parent element is the `<div>`, having class `extra`. The `<span>` tag within the `<div>` most-specifically matches `.extra span {}`, which instructs it to *inherit it's color property from its parent-element*, which, in this case, is the `<div class="extra">`, which has an inline style of `color: green`. So, the text appears green because the `<div>` has a color of green.

It's important to not get confused and think that `inherit` inherits from other CSS-rules up the chain (like `span {}`): no, it inherits from the properties of its parent element, `<div>`!

**Edit**

I also found a blog article that covers this a bit more comprehensively, including, as @steveax mentioned in a comment below, how `color` is inherited by default and can be a bad example. But, as mentioned in this blog post, most browsers use a default stylesheet that colors links blue, and in such a case, the `color: inherit` property can override this, causing link color to be the same as the parent element. We can see this by modifying our original example (you can do this in the TryIt Editor and see for yourself):

Let's add a new CSS block:

```
.extra a {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Now let's change our `<div class="extra">` to include a link:

```
<div class="extra" style="color:green">
Here is <span>a span element</span> which is green, because it inherits from its parent. Here is <a href="#">A Link</a>.
</div>
```

As you can see, the link is now green instead of blue. If we remove our `.extra a {}` block, the link becomes blue.

Comment: That's a confusing example as [`color` is inherited by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color)

Comment: It is, yes, but unfortunately that was the example that the OP provided, so that's what we had to work with. I added a new section at the bottom discussing this and providing an example where `inherit` for `color` would be applicable. Thanks @steveax!

Comment: But Why didn't use     .extra  in 3rd case ( style="color:red" )?

Comment: That's because `<div style="color:red">` doesn't use `class="extra"`, so `.extra` doesn't apply to it. `.extra` denotes that the block applies to elements having `class="extra"`.

Answer (score 1):

In the `class` of `"extra"`, the `span` element has been defined to `inherit`. That is set by these lines within the HTML `<style>` tags:

```
.extra span {
    color: inherit;
}
```

So, any `span` element within a parent of `class="extra"` will inherit its colour from that said parent.

Within the HTML `<BODY>` tag, there are three `<div>` elements. The second of which has the `class` of `"extra"` assigned to it:

```
<div class="extra" style="color:green">
Here is <span>a span element</span> which is green, because it inherits from its parent.
</div>
```

That same `<div>` also has a `style` of `color:green`. This `<div>` element is the *parent* of its `<span>` element (because the `<span>` element is contained within the`<div>` tags), and so the `<span>` is also has the `class` of `"extra"` assigned to it and so it will inherit the colour of that `<div>` (its parent), and so it is green, also.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp

It gets its CSS property from its parent.  For example

```
#1{
     color :red;
}

#2{
     color : inherit;
}
```

with the following HTML :

```
<div id="1">
     Hello!
     <div id="2">
          I am another div!
     </div>
</div>
```

Will cause the div under the id of 2 to have the same color of its parent object, in this case, div 1.  So, the color would be red.

Comment: It would be red without the second rule as [`color` is inherited by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color)